# Error while running PostgresSQL for node.js

Tags: postgresql

Command:- psql -U postgres -d postgres

Error:- 'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install postgres? On linux you need at least the postgresql-client-nn package to install psql.

Comment: I installed postgres and I am working on windows

Comment: Make sure your program_files/PostgreSQL/ver/bin directory is in your PATH...

Comment: If you're using the `pg` module, try using the pure JS client instead of the "native" one. Or other way around. Of course this doesn't solve the real problem, that your Postgres client doesn't seem to be installed properly.